# Set itertools product repeat value per element

Tags: python, python-itertools

If I run the code

```py
import itertools

products = itertools.product([0,1],repeat=3)
print(list(products))
```

I get the following output:

`[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]`

However, I would only like to repeat the `0`  once and the `1` twice. In other words, I want the following output:

`[(0, 1, 1),  (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)]`

How can I achieve this?

---

Of course, I could do:

```py
import itertools

products = itertools.permutations([0,1,1],3)
print(list(set(products)))
```

but in my case there is a large number of elements so that calling `set` before iteration will kill the code due to memory issues.

Comment: Can you clarify what your practical requirements are? There are different ways to interpret your requirement, and the use of immutable, indistinguishable elements does not help separating them. E.g. is it important to use ``1`` twice, or could one use ``1`` and ``1``? Is there always a single "``0``" and n "``1``s" or can there be other elements as well?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it will always involve only 0s and 1s that are indistinguishable, but their repeat number can be anything. For example, 10 0s and 4 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 0's and 1's this would work:

```
from itertools import combinations

def gen(n0, n1):
    n = n0 + n1
    for c in combinations(range(n), n1):
        out = [0]*n
        for i in c:
            out[i]=1
        yield out

list(gen(1,2))
```

The way to build `out` may not be the most optimal, but the idea is there, I'll leave it to you to improve on it if time efficiency is an issue.

Generalizing one step further:

```
def gen(n0, n1, n2):
    n12 = n1 + n2
    n = n0 + n12
    for c12 in combinations(range(n), n12):
        out = [0]*n
        for i in c12:
            out[i] = 1
        for c2 in combinations(c12, n2):
            out_ = out.copy()
            for i in c2:
                out_[i] = 2
            yield out_
```

Again the construction of `out_` is likely suboptimal. And with the same idea you can keep nesting to more and more different elements. And if you have more possible elements that the depth becomes cumbersome to nest by hand, you can recursify the process, which is a fun exercise too:

```
def gen(ns, elems=None, C=None, out=None):
    
    if elems is None:
        elems = list(range(len(ns)))
    else:
        assert len(elems) == len(ns)
        
    if out is None:
        N = 1
        for n in ns:
            N *= n
        out = [elems[0]]*N
        C = range(N)
    
    if len(ns) == 1:
        yield out
    
    else:
        n = ns[-1]
        e = elems[-1]
        
        for c in combinations(C,n):
            out_ = out.copy()
            for i in c:
                out_[i] = e
            C_ = [i for i in C if i not in c]
            yield from gen(ns[:-1], elems[:-1], C_, out_)
```

Comment: what is output for your own example : `permutations of 3 0s, 4 1s, 1 2 and 2 3s, ie of (0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,3,3) for example... (not the DV by the way)`

Comment: OP has now clarified they only have 0s and 1s...

Comment: @Julien, thanks for the answer. Is there an easy way to extend this to more numbers (so x 0s, y 1s and z 2s)?

Comment: Please see edit :).

Comment: And here you go for the general recursive version :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be overly specialized to your example, but

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> t = namedtuple('t', 'v1 v2 v3')
>>> [tuple(t(1,1,1)._replace(**{x: 0})) for x in t._fields]
[(0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you, definitely a solution but the only issue I have is that I deal with a lot of elements so that I get issues when storing them directly in memory. Itertools allows me to access the products one by one

Comment: I only used a list comprehension for the example. You can use a generator expression instead (`(tuple(...) for x in t._fields)`) to generate values on demand.